# CSS dynamic Text gradient

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

I Want to **Gradient Some Text**, I done it Using Following Code.
The Problem is,

> It works on Chrome,But didn't work on Internet Explorer

Another thing it applies **horizontally**

> I want it **Vertically**, More specifically in **45 Angle position**, **center focused** or **Circular Gradient**

Style Sheet:

```
<style>
h1 {
   font-size: 60px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(RED, GREEN, BLUE);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

p {
   font-size: 18px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(RED, GREEN, BLUE);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Tags:

```
<h1>I Want Gradient</h1>
<p>I want to apply Some Gradient<br/>ON Given Paragraph With<br/>Different angles and<br/>With Different Styles</p>
```

> Result on Chrome:

[image: Result on Chrome]

> Result on IE:

[image: Result on IE]

Please help me, Thanks,

Comment: Gradients are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient) on IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Actually the `background-clip` is only supported on `-webkit-` browsers, so that won't work either. Only option I can think of to make it work is using `svg`'s gradients and `mask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a Circle Gradient example: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/74/

```
<div>
    <h1 class="grad1">I Want Gradient</h1>
    <br/>
    <p class="grad1">I want to apply Some Gradient<br/>ON Given Paragraph With<br/>Different angles and<br/>With Different Styles</p>
</div>

.grad1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red 5%, green 15%, blue 60%); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(red 5%, green 15%, blue 60%); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(red 5%, green 15%, blue 60%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient(red 5%, green 15%, blue 60%); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: background clipping does not work on non-webkit browsers

Answer (score 2):

Here's 45 degree angle gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/75/

```
.grad1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,red,yellow,green);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,red,yellow,green);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Angle Problem Also Solved,Is there any way I could make it work on most popular browser?